# function that receives a letter then returns the next and previous letters c++

Tags: function, visual-c++, char, void, static-cast

Write a function that receives a letter then returns the next and previous letters.
and this is my Solution

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void letter(char &x);
int main(){
    char a;
    cout<<"Enter your letter\n:";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<letter(a)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;}
void letter(char &x){
    cout<<x+1<<"  "<<x-1<<endl;
}
```

**while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, void)'**
what is that mean ?

Comment: `letter(a)` returns `void`. You can't print `void`.

Comment: `cout<<letter(a)<<endl;`, letter(a) is void.

Comment: i solve my problem but the output was numbers how i can Conversion to letter ?

Comment: `cout << char(x + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<letter(a)<<endl;
```

that have no sense, it's the same that

```
cout<< void << endl;
```

becouse your "letter(a)" function return nothing.
maybe what you want to change it for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void letter(char &x);
int main(){
    char a;
    cout<<"Enter your letter\n:";
    cin>>a;
    letter(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void letter(char &x){
    cout<<x+1<<"  "<<x-1<<endl;
}
```